# How can I put the right bracket of the matrix to the left, because it is almost at the end of the sheet?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\providecommand{\abs}[2]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Paquete para codigo MATLAB
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{azul}{rgb}{0.17, 0.40, 0.69}
\definecolor{negro}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
 backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
 commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
 keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
 stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
 basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
 breakatwhitespace=false,         
 breaklines=true,                 
 captionpos=b,                    
 keepspaces=true,                 
 numbers=left,                    
 numbersep=5pt,                  
 showspaces=false,                
 showstringspaces=false,
 showtabs=false,                  
 tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
%Fin de configuracion para MATLAB CODE
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{J.Leonardo}
\title{Laboratorio 1}
\begin{document}

\include{caratula}
\pagebreak

\begin{enumerate}
\item  \textbf{Sistema de ecuaciones Método del Punto Fijo y Método de Newton}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph{*}),leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=15pt] 
\item Sea $\textit{D} =  \lbrace(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus 0\leq x\leq2,  0\leq y\leq2\rbrace $ . Sea $G = (g_{1},g_{2}) : D\rightarrow D$ una contracción con:\\
\vspace{5mm} \ \\
$g_{1}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2\hspace{1mm} + 3y^2\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20},g_{2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3\hspace{1mm} + x\cdot y^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40}$ \par
\vspace{3mm} \ \\
Si se cumple que $\Vert JG(x,y) \Vert <  \lambda < 1.$ 
Calcule el valor de $\lambda.$\par
Sea $x_{0}=0$ , $y_{0}=0$ , el punto inicial luego defina $x_{n+1}=g_{1}(x_{n},y_{n})$ , $y_{n+1}=g_{2}(x_{n},y_{n})$ como la iteración del punto fijo , que resuelve el sistema $g_{1}(x,y)=x$ , $g_{2}(x,y)=y$.\par 
Calcule el número de iteraciones $n$ para alcanzar un error menor a 5 cifras decimales (Tol $<10^{-6}$)\\
\\\textbf{\textit{Solución}}\\
\\Sea $D=[0,2] \times [0,2] $ , veamos si $g_{1}(x,y)$ esta bien definida:
\begin{center}
$g_{1}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2\hspace{1mm} + 3y^2\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} \leq \dfrac{2^2\hspace{1mm} + 3(2^2)\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} $\par
\vspace{1mm}
$\dfrac{x^2\hspace{1mm} + 3y^2\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} \leq 2$
\end{center}
Igualmente: 
\begin{center}
$g_{1}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2\hspace{1mm} + 3y^2\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} \geq \dfrac{0^2\hspace{1mm} + 3(0^2)\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} $\par
\vspace{1mm}
$\dfrac{x^2\hspace{1mm} + 3y^2\hspace{1mm} + 24}{20} \geq \dfrac{24}{20} > 0$
\end{center}
\vspace{1mm}
Como $0<g_{1}(x,y)\leq 2$ entonces $g_{1}(x,y) \in [0,2]$, decimos que $g_{1}(x,y)$ esta bien definida.\\
Sea $D=[0,2] \times [0,2] $ , veamos si $g_{2}(x,y)$ esta bien definida:
\begin{center}
$g_{2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3\hspace{1mm} + x\cdot y^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} \leq \dfrac{2^3\hspace{1mm} + 2\cdot 2^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} $\par
\vspace{1mm}
$\dfrac{x^3\hspace{1mm} + x\cdot y^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} \leq 2$
\end{center}
Igualmente:
\begin{center}
$g_{2}(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3\hspace{1mm} + x\cdot y^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} \geq \dfrac{0^3\hspace{1mm} + 0\cdot 0^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} $\par
\vspace{1mm}
$ \dfrac{x^3\hspace{1mm} + x\cdot y^{2}\hspace{1mm} + 64}{40} \geq \dfrac{64}{40} > 0$
\end{center}
\vspace{1mm}
Como $0<g_{2}(x,y)\leq 2$ entonces $g_{2}(x,y) \in [0,2]$, decimos que $g_{2}(x,y)$ esta bien definida.\\
\\Ahora veamos si $D$ es una contracción

\[
\mathbf{JG} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} & 
    \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial y} \\[2ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \dfrac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} & 
    \dfrac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}   \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{x}{10}& 
    \dfrac{3y}{10} \\[2ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \dfrac{3x^{2}+y^{2}}{40} & 
    \dfrac{x\cdot y}{20}   \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\newpage
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
\begin{center}
$\Vert JH(x,y) \Vert_{\infty} = MAX(\dfrac{x}{10} +\dfrac{3y}{10} ; \dfrac{3x^{2}+y^{2}}{40} +  \dfrac{x\cdot y}{20} )\leq MAX(\dfrac{2}{10} +\dfrac{3\cdot 2}{10} ; \dfrac{3\cdot 2^{2}+2^{2}}{40} +  \dfrac{2\cdot 2}{20} ) $
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
$\Vert JH(x,y) \Vert_{\infty}\leq MAX ( 0.8 ; 0.6) $
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
$\Vert JH(x,y) \Vert_{\infty}\leq 0.8 \leq 1$\\
\vspace{3mm} \ \\
Entonces $\lambda = 0.8$
\end{center}
Ahora hallaremos el número de iteraciones:\\
\begin{center}
$n = \dfrac{\log \dfrac{(1-\lambda)\cdot T}{\Vert Z_{1}-Z_{0} \Vert_{\infty}}}{\log \lambda}$
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
$Z_{n+1} =(g_{1}(x_{n},y_{n});  g_{2}(x_{n},y_{n} ) = (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})$
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
$Z_{1} =(g_{1}(0,0);  g_{2}(0,0 ) = (x_{1}, y_{1})=(\dfrac{6}{5},\dfrac{8}{5})$
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
$\Vert Z_{1}-Z_{0} \Vert_{\infty} = \Vert( \dfrac{6}{5},\dfrac{8}{5})-(0,0)\Vert_{\infty}=MAX( \dfrac{6}{5},\dfrac{8}{5})=\dfrac{8}{5} = 1,6$
\vspace{8mm} \ \\
\end{center}
Tenemos $\lambda = 0.8$ y $T = 10^{-6}$ entonces reemplazamos todos los datos en la formula de $n$:
\vspace{4mm} \ \\
\begin{center}
$n = \dfrac{\log \dfrac{(1-0.8)\cdot 10^{-6}}{1.6}}{\log 0.8}= 71.232$
\vspace{4mm} \ \\
$n\geq 72$
\vspace{4mm} \ \\
$n_{min}=72$
\end{center}
\vspace{6mm} \ \\
\newpage
\item Implemente un algoritmo en Matlab que permita calcular la solución del sistema del inciso (a) con 6 cifras decimales exactas por el método del Punto Fijo. Calcule el número mínimo de iteraciones necesarias con la condición de parada en dicho algoritmo y compare con el valor encontrado en (a). Muestre el algoritmo y los resultados de la ejecución del algoritmo mediante una tabla detallada.
\vspace{3mm} \ \\
\\\textbf{\textit{Solución}}\\
\\Implementaremos un algoritmo en Matlab que nos permita alcular la solución del sistema del inciso (a) con 6 cifras decimales exactas por el método del Punto Fijo \\
\\\textbf{\textit{Código de Matlab}}

\lstinputlisting[ language=Octave,lastline=28]{MetodoPuntoFijo1.m}

\textbf{\textit{Salida de Matlab}}
\begin{lstlisting}
Método del Punto Fijo
    Sistemas no lineales x=(x^(2)+3*y^(2)+24)/20 e y=(x^(3)+x*y^(2)+64)/40
    Iteracion       Xn          Yn              f1(x,y)     f2(x,y)
     0         0.000000000   0.000000000    1.200000000    1.600000000
     1         1.200000000   1.600000000    1.656000000    1.720000000
     2         1.656000000   1.720000000    1.780876800    1.836010470
     3         1.780876800   1.836010470    1.864216276    1.891282730
     4         1.864216276   1.891282730    1.910307671    1.928673106
     5         1.910307671   1.928673106    1.940430762    1.951929074
     6         1.940430762   1.951929074    1.959767644    1.967483564
     7         1.959767644   1.967483564    1.972683197    1.977827562
     8         1.972683197   1.977827562    1.981344230    1.984835026
     9         1.981344230   1.984835026    1.987221760    1.989596423
    10         1.987221760   1.989596423    1.991226605    1.992851100
    11         1.991226605   1.992851100    1.993967496    1.995081207
    12         1.993967496   1.995081207    1.995847672    1.996612866
    13         1.995847672   1.996612866    1.997139837    1.997666206
    14         1.997139837   1.997666206    1.998028917    1.998391342
    15         1.998028917   1.998391342    1.998641171    1.998890864
    16         1.998641171   1.998890864    1.999063029    1.999235130
    17         1.999063029   1.999235130    1.999353816    1.999472470
    18         1.999353816   1.999472470    1.999554308    1.999636131
    19         1.999554308   1.999636131    1.999692570    1.999749002
    20         1.999692570   1.999749002    1.999787929    1.999826853
    21         1.999787929   1.999826853    1.999853705    1.999880554
    22         1.999853705   1.999880554    1.999899077    1.999917598
    23         1.999899077   1.999917598    1.999930376    1.999943153
    24         1.999930376   1.999943153    1.999951968    1.999960782
    25         1.999951968   1.999960782    1.999966863    1.999972944
    26         1.999966863   1.999972944    1.999977139    1.999981334
    27         1.999977139   1.999981334    1.999984229    1.999987123
    28         1.999984229   1.999987123    1.999989119    1.999991116
    29         1.999989119   1.999991116    1.999992494    1.999993871
    30         1.999992494   1.999993871    1.999994821    1.999995772
    31         1.999994821   1.999995772    1.999996427    1.999997083
    32         1.999996427   1.999997083    1.999997535    1.999997987
    33         1.999997535   1.999997987    1.999998300    1.999998612
    El numero mínimo de iteraciones es: 34
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{3mm} \ \\
Como podemos ver, con nuestro programa en Matlab el número de iteraciones es 34 mientras que en el inciso (a) la fórmula nos dio como estimación 72 iteraciones, con lo cual se ve que la fórmula no es precisa y es solo una acotación que sirve de guía.
\vspace{5mm} \ \\
\item Al resolver el sistema siguiente por el método de Newton-Raphson:
\vspace{5mm} \ \\
$f_{1}(x,y)= x^{2}-y-3=0 , f_{2}(x,y)= x + exp(y) -4 =0\hspace{2mm} ,\hspace{2mm} F =(f_{1}, f_{2})$\\
\vspace{2mm} \ \\
Obtenemos una sucesión recurrente $z_{n} = ( x_{n},y_{n})\hspace{2mm}$, definida por:
\begin{center}
 $z_{n+1}=\hspace{2mm} z_{n} - ((JF)^{-1}\cdot F)(z_{n})$
\end{center}
Luego:
\begin{center}
 $x_{n+1}=A(x_{n},y_{n}) ,  y_{n+1}=B(x_{n},y_{n})$
\end{center}
\vspace{2mm} \ \\
Encuentre las funciones $A$ y $B$ en términos de $x,y$.
\vspace{3mm} \ \\
\\\textbf{\textit{Solución}}\\
\\Sean:
\begin{center}
$f_{1}(x,y)= x^{2}-y-3\hspace{2mm} \wedge\hspace{2mm} f_{2}(x,y)= x + exp(y) -4 $\\
\vspace{2mm} \ \\
\end{center}
 De la sucesión recurrente $z_{n+1}=( x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ y $z_{n}=( x_{n},y_{n})  $
\[
\mathbf{JF}_{(x,y)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & 
    \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\[2ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & 
    \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}   \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  2x& 
  -1 \\[2ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  1 & 
   e^{y}   \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\newpage
\vspace{2mm} \ \\
Calculamos la Matriz Inversa del Jacobiano
\[
\mathbf{(JF)}_{(x,y)}^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{e^{y}}{2x\cdot e^{y}+ 1} & 
      \dfrac{1}{2x\cdot e^{y}+ 1}  \\[2ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \dfrac{-1}{2x\cdot e^{y}+ 1} & 
    \dfrac{2x}{2x\cdot e^{y}+ 1}  \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
 
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{n+1} & \\[2ex]
  y_{n+1} \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{n} & \\[2ex]
  y_{n} \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
-
\mathbf{(JF)}_{(x,y)}^{-1} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
  f_{1}(x,y) & \\[2ex]
  f_{2}(x,y)\\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{n+1} & \\[2ex]
  y_{n+1} \\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{e^{-y_{n}}\cdot(4(y_{n}+2)\cdot e^{2y_{n}}+16\cdot e^{y_{n}} +1)}{4\cdot (2\cdot x_{n}\cdot e^{y_{n}}+1)} + \dfrac{x_{n}}{2}- \dfrac{e^{-y_{n}}}{4}  & \\[2ex]
     \dfrac{-e^{-2y_{n}}\cdot(4(y_{n}+2)\cdot e^{2y_{n}}+16\cdot e^{y_{n}} +1)}{4\cdot (2x_{n}\cdot e^{y_{n}}+1)} -\dfrac{x_{n}\cdot e^{-y_{n} }}{2}+\dfrac{(16\cdot e^{y_{n}}+1)\cdot e^{-2y_{n}}}{4} + y_{n}-1\\[2ex]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

How can I put the right bracket of the matrix to the left, because it is almost at the end of the sheet, look the picture and code please.

Comment: Your code is anything but minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of the 14 `\cdot` instructions and the unnecessary second columns in the `bmatrix` environments gets the job done.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%% Note that I've streamlined both the preamble and the body of your
%% test document.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'latin1' -- are you serious?
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb' package
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%\usepackage{enumerate} % don't load both 'enumerate' and 'enumitem'
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{n+1} \\
  y_{n+1} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dfrac{e^{-y_{n}}(4(y_{n}+2) e^{2y_{n}}+16 e^{y_{n}} +1)}{4 (2 x_{n} e^{y_{n}}+1)} 
      + \dfrac{x_{n}}{2} - \dfrac{e^{-y_{n}}}{4} \\[2ex]
  \dfrac{-e^{-2y_{n}}(4(y_{n}+2) e^{2y_{n}}+16 e^{y_{n}} +1)}{4 (2x_{n} e^{y_{n}}+1)} 
      - \dfrac{x_{n} e^{-y_{n} }}{2} + \dfrac{(16 e^{y_{n}}+1) e^{-2y_{n}}}{4} 
      + y_{n}-1
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```